# Digitar somente letras e ponto

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo uma página com um login e senha que busca os dados no AD da empresa. Estou usando o PHP e preciso de alguma forma permitir somente letras e ponto (.) no campo de login. Estou usando o script abaixo, é bem básico mas funciona em partes. Quando eu digito um número, ele aparece no campo, mesmo usando onkeypress ou onkeyup. Existe alguma forma de ele bloquear mesmo, nem aparecer no campo o caractere inválido?

```js
function somente_letras(campo){
    var digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz.";
    var campo_temp;
       for (var i=0;i<campo.value.length;i++){
          campo_temp=campo.value.substring(i,i+1);
              if (digits.indexOf(campo_temp)==-1){
                campo.value = campo.value.substring(0,i);
                return false;
              }
        }
}
```

Comment: o que significa caractere inválido nesse contexto?

Comment: Números, letras com acento e outros simbolos, exceto o ponto (.). Só isso seria "valido" no contexto da página: digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz."

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp
**onkeydown**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer usando a expressão regular `[a-zA-Z.]`, assim:

```js
jQuery('.meucampo').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z.]/g,'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="meucampo" value="" />
```

Comment: exato, com a sua idéia deu certo. Obrigado.

Comment: Amigo como faço pra que quando eu der "espaço" ele dê o "espaço" e não apague o "espaço"? Quero colocá-lo em um input onde a pessoa digita o nome dela.

Answer (score 5):

Veja se essa função funciona da forma que você precisa:

```
function somente_letras() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\w\.]|\d/g, '');
};
```

Onde:

```
document.getElementById("campo").onkeyup = somente_letras;
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6duqp4df/1/)**</kbd>

Um problema com essa forma de filtrar os caracteres no campo é que as teclas de controle do teclado também não funcionam, como por exemplo as teclas de seta, Ctrl+A ou Home e End. Para as teclas de seta é possível detectar o código da tecla com [esse if](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807387/1267304):

```
var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

// do nothing if it's an arrow key
if(code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40) {
    return;
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6duqp4df/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Ele preferiu usando jquery. Quanto mais javascript puro, melhor.

Comment: @EduardoSeixas não usei jQuery porque no código dele não havia e nem a tag foi usada, mas enfim...