# JavaScript para retirar acentos e caracteres especiais não funciona da mesma forma em todos os browsers ?

Tags: javascript, java, jsf

Tenho o seguinte JavaScript:

```
function validaCaracteres(strToReplace) {
strSChar = "áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçÁÀÃÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇ";
strNoSChars = "aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC";
var newStr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < strToReplace.length; i++) {
    if (strSChar.indexOf(strToReplace.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        newStr += strNoSChars.substr(strSChar.search(strToReplace.substr(i, 1)), 1);
    } else {
        newStr += strToReplace.substr(i, 1);
    }
}

return newStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]/g, '').toUpperCase();
```

}

A finalidade dele é retirar os caracteres especiais em tempo de digitação, caracteres especiais, acentos e caso a String seja minúscula retorná-la maiúscula em tempo de digitação.

Porém, ocorre o seguinte erro, ele funciona diferente em determinados Browsers, como o IE, ela não permite o posicionamento dentro da String, enviando para a última posição da String, não permite a reedição do Texto.

Preciso que caso o texto seja digitado errado tenha a opção de reeditá-lo.

Existe alguma forma de se fazer isso ?

Estou chamando essa função dessa forma:

```
<h:inputText value="#{manBean.manVO.field}" 
                        onblur="this.value = validaCaracteres(this.value);"
                        onkeyup="this.value = validaCaracteres(this.value);"
                        onkeydown="this.value = validaCaracteres(this.value);"/>
```

Existe alguma outra forma de se fazer isso, podendo utilizar a reedição do texto ?

Desde já agradeço !

Comment: Caramba, acho que esse código deve rolar há uns 10 anos na net...

Comment: Conhece algum que faça isso também ? da forma que eu preciso ?

Comment: [Nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83165/75) tem duas demos, na segunda mostra como possibilitar a navegação pelo campo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu finalizei usando o onkeypress

```
onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 65 || event.which &gt; 93 ) if(event.which &lt; 97 || event.which &gt; 122 ) if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57 ) if(event.which != 8) if(event.which != 32) if(event.which != 45) if(event.which != 95) return false;"/>
```

Obrigado !

Answer (score 3):

olha, você pode usar script <kbd>[fold-to-ascii](https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii/blob/eae6030cc155a59fe7859666b4fb45171c67a17f/fold-to-ascii.js)</kbd> para remover os caracteres especiais e os acentos.

No lugar de usar o evento `onblur`, `onkeyup` e `onkeydown`, use apena so `oninput`, pois ele é disparado sempre que o usuario insere algum texto no input.

```js
var teste = document.getElementById("teste");
teste.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
 event.target.value = foldToASCII(event.target.value).toUpperCase();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii/eae6030cc155a59fe7859666b4fb45171c67a17f/fold-to-ascii.js"></script>
<input id="teste" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Segue função simples em JS para retirar acentos e caracteres especiais. Funciona em qualquer browser:

```js
function retira_acentos(str) {
 com_acento = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŔÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿŕ";
 sem_acento = "AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYRsBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuybyr";
 novastr="";
 for(i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
  troca=false;
  for (a=0; a<com_acento.length; a++) {
   if (str.substr(i,1)==com_acento.substr(a,1)) {
    novastr+=sem_acento.substr(a,1);
    troca=true;
    break;
   }
  }
  if (troca==false) {
   novastr+=str.substr(i,1);
  }
 }
 return novastr;
}  

var palavras="Último coração alumínio latência opções blablabla...";
alert (retira_acentos(palavras));
```